# Kali Linux missing ath10k firmware (Not seeing all available wifi networks)

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, kali-linux, firmware

I've recently installed Kali Linux 2020.2 on my acer laptop. During the installation it said that it is missing ath10k/pre-cal-pci-0000:03:00.0.bin firmware. I couldn't find the solution for that so i continued on with my installation. When it asked me to connect to the wifi i could see some of the neighbour's networks, but not mine. I just plugged in ethernet cable and continued. Now that i have it installed i tried to connect to my wifi but it still wouldn't show it and is still showing some other networks(but not all that are available). Does anyone know how to fix that? I tried installing firmware from github but I think I didn't do it right. Can anyone guide me thru that process? I'm sure that both my router and my wifi adapter(inside laptop) are set correctly because i can connect to my network using windows 10 on the same computer(I'm using dual boot).I also tried installing older version of Kali but i still got the same problem. I've found these two links that might help: https://github.com/ajaybhatia/Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, last month there was a bug in the linux kernel connected to atheros devices.

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208251

At this point, we're waiting for the patch.

A temporary solution is downgrade the kernel or install kali linux with an older kernel.